# How does Ash figure the year is 1300 A.D.?

Tags: time-travel, army-of-darkness

In the legendary comedy-horror *Army of Darkness* (1992), Bruce Campbell's narration opens the film thus:

> My name is Ash, and I am a slave. As close as I can figure it, the year is 1300 A.D., and I am being dragged to my death. It wasn't always like this. I had a real life... once.

How does Ash figure the year? Do *we* know the year, apart from his figuring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Evil Dead series includes *The Evil Dead* (1981), *Evil Dead II* (1987), and *Army of Darkness* (1992).

Thus Ash's era in the 20th century should be sometime within the period of about 1975 to 2000.

According to Greendrake's answer, at the end of *Army of Darkness* (1992) Ash is told:

> The book tells us that each drop allows a man to sleep for a century. Swallow six drops and thou shell awaken in thine own time.

So if they think that six drops of a magic potion will send Ash 600 years into the future, and Ash has told them what year he comes from, the year Ash is in should be about AD 1375 to AD 1400.

And if Ash is actually in the year AD 1300, six drops should send him to AD 1900, a year when nobody knows him and where life is, on the average, much worse than in AD 2000 or even AD 1975, though Ash's knowledge of future future economic and political events and future inventions might enable him to become rich.

If one drop of the magic potion will make someone sleep for 100 years plus or minus  5 years, six drops should make Ash sleep for 570 to 630 years, and end up in 1870 to 1930 if he is given them in the year 1300.

If one drop of the magic potion will make someone sleep for 100 years plus or minus  10 years, six drops should make Ash sleep for 540 to 660 years, and end up in 1870 to 1960 if he is given them in the year 1300.

If one drop of the magic potion will make someone sleep for 100 years plus or minus  20 years, six drops should make Ash sleep for 480 to 720 years, and end up in 1780 to 2020 if he is given them in the year 1300.

And maybe the wise men calculated that Ash's time was not exactly 600 years in the future, but more like 625 years, and thought that six drops would take him closer to his time than seven drops would, especially if there was any uncertainty about how long a drop would make Ash sleep.

At the beginning of *Army of Darkness* (1992) Ash's narration says:

> My name is Ash, and I am a slave. As close as I can figure it, the year is 1300 A.D., and I am being dragged to my death. It wasn't always like this. I had a real life... once.

I imagine there was a longer or shorter period of time after that opening narration, showing Ash appearing in the past and having various adventures before being dragged to death when the narration would be thought or spoken by Ash.  I don't know how much time Ash had to ask people what year it was.  And I don't know how much quiet time Ash had to notice details and decide what year he was in.

I note that Ash says:

> ...As close as I can figure it, the year is 1300 A.D., and I am being dragged to my death...

This implies that he wasn't told the year.  Most people in Europe would at least know the year number in the local calendar era.  And most people in most parts of Catholic Europe would be using the *Anno Domini* calendar era.

In still pagan Lithuania most people would use some native pagan calendar, except those who had some sort of business with Christian outsiders. Lithuania eventually conquered a lot of Christian regions, where both Lithuanian and Christian calendar eras would be used by different people, and converted to Catholicism by baout 1400.

In Eastern Orthodox lands like the eastern Roman Empire, Bulgaria, Serbia, Russia, etc. years were counted from the biblical creation of the world.

> The Byzantine Anno Mundi era was the official calendar of the Eastern Orthodox Church from c. AD 691 to 1728 in the Ecumenical Patriarchate. By the late 10th century the Byzantine era, which had become fixed at 1 September 5509 BCE since at least the mid-7th century (differing by 16 years from the Alexandrian date, and by 2 years from the Chronicon Paschale), had become the widely accepted calendar by Chalcedonian Christianity. The Byzantine era was used as the civil calendar by the Byzantine Empire from AD 988 to 1453, and by Russia from c. AD 988 to 1699.[34][better source needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi#Adoption_of_Byzantine_era

And in the Catholic Iberian Peninsula the Spanish era or era of Caesar starting in 38 BC was used until the late Middle Ages by the various kingdoms.

> Official usage of the era ceased in different parts of the peninsula at different times: Catalonia dropped the era (as well as the French king's regnal year) in AD 1180, Aragon in 1349/1350, Valencia in 1358, Castile in 1382/1383, Portugal in 1420/1422 and Navarre in the early 15th century.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_era)[4] While the year officially began on 1 January under the Spanish era, that was changed to 25 December when the Anno Domini system was adopted (while the Church used 11 January).[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_era)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_era

And by the late Middle Ages our *Anno Domini* calendar era was used in all parts of Catholic Europe except the Iberian peninsula.

So in the late Middle Ages if Ash asked what year it was most people in Catholic Europe should have able to tell him whether it was 1275, 1350, or 1432, for example.  And Ash would not be misled by use of a different calendar era except in the Iberian Peninsula, which might make Ash think it was AD 1300 when it was really AD 1262.  So if Iberian wise men gave Ash 6 magic sleeping drops he should awake in AD 1862.

So I don't think Ash was told the year by anyone but merely deduced it from various factors.

No doubt an expert on Medieval history could make a good guess at the year if transported back in time.

My guess would not be as good as an expert's but way better than most people's.

Most people would have a very had time figuring out which historical era they were in.

And I guess the makers of *Army of Darkness* (1992) probably chose the cheapest Medieval costumes and props they could make, rent, or buy, instead of worrying about accuracy.

I kind of have the feeling that if Ash has the historical knowledge of most modern people, he would really make an "ash" out of himself trying to figure out when he was.

Since Ash guessed the year was 1300 and a year around 1380 would be about 600 years before Ash's time, I should point out that there were a lot of changes in the 14th century (1301-1400).

In 1300 men wore loose fitting gowns or robes down to about their ankles.  In 1400 men wore tights and tailored jackets, typical "medieval" garb in most people's imagination.  And I'm sure female dress changed a bit during that century too, even though I can't think of the ways it did.

In 1300 the most expensive armor was chain mail.  In 1400 the most expensive armor was plate armor.

In 1400 mechanical clocks, usually on towers of public building for people to see the time, would have been much more common in cities and towns than in 1300.

One way to tell the era would be to ask who the local king was. But in the Middle Ages it was extremely rare to use regnal numbers for kings.  Usually only popes and emperors used regnal numbers in the Middle Ages.

So if someone who knew a bit about Medieval history asked for the name of the king and the three previous kings in England during the 14th century, the answer would range from Edward, Henry, John, and Richard in 1300 to Henry or Richard, Edward, Edward, and Edward in 1399.

Europeans had black powder by the late 13th century.  The first recorded us of a cannon in Europe was in 1326.  And the use of cannons and hand guns became more common in warfare during the rest of the century.  So if there is an army of humans in *Army of Darkness* (1992) the type of armor and the possible use of gunpowder weapons might be a clue to how well Ash guessed the date.

Comment: I can only imagine this was downvoted because somebody thought it was written by AI. But it's not. If you actually read it, it is a logical and meticulous consideration. The only thing it doesn't explore is eclipses (ha!), which _I_ only know about because that's how Twain does it in _Connecticut Yankee_. Thanks! (The only reason _I_ didn't assume it was AI is that I recognized Golding from other sites and know they are a solid citizen.)

Answer (score 5):

> Do *we* know the year

We know from the filmmakers that the plot was intended to be set in 1300. This was their [original intention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Darkness#Development) for *Evil Dead II*, which they got to realizing in *Army of Darkness* (and in the ending of *Evil Dead II*).

However, in the original ending, the Wise Man tells Ash when preparing his dormitive serum:

> The book tells us that each drop allows a man to sleep for a century. Swallow six drops and thou shell awaken in thine own time.

[image]

As Ash's own time is the end of the 20th century, we get the Medieval time close to 1400.

> How does Ash figure the year?

It is unclear, but apparently he guesstimated it from the appearance, outfit and munition of the warriors who took him captive — which supposedly belonged to Medieval England around 1300.

Comment: Yeah, I also figured it would be from the attire - late medieval period - when the good times went sour and the plague was getting going, general misery, etc, would suit the period that he looked to be in.